# How do I optimise O(n^2)

Tags: algorithm, loops, big-o

I am having an array a1[] of size more than 1000. Each array elements contains array of size 100 or more.

I am looping first array a1 and within the loop I am again looping elements of a1.

This is slow and probably is O(nm).

How can I optimise this ?

```
foreach ($a1 as $key => $values) {
     foreach ($values as $k => $v) {
      $obj->insertIntoTable($v); // This is a db operations it takes time too
 }
}
```

Comment: How can it possibly be less than `O(N^2)` (assuming `N` the size of the outer and inner arrays). You need to read all of these `N^2` elements in any case. Can you clarify your question?

Comment: No, it's not O(N^2), it's O(N).

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen How do you get that? Are you assuming the inner arrays to be of bounded size? Or are you assuming `N` to be the total input length?

Comment: How is it O(N)? It's O(nm)  since the outer array and inner array's sizes are different

Comment: OP, I think you're falling into the trap of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You should rethink your architecture/logic around that insertion and ask question regarding that

Comment: @SiddharthaChoubey Insert in batch and not one by one. Just be aware to not exceed max_allowed_packets though.

Comment: You're doing 1 operation N times, the N is just split into a an array of 100-(or so)-elements arrays. There's no indication in the post that the length of each sub-array is related to the length of the overall array, in which case doubling the size of the outer array would double the workload, and that is O(N).

Comment: In any case, the expensive operation here is the insert operation, and that has to be performed on every item. There's no way to optimize this unless you make the insert operation cheaper, or you reduce the number of items.

Comment: If you think this is O(N^2) I would like a clear explanation of what N denotes in this case.

Comment: O(nm) is good as well, it depends on how you count the things you're doing. If there's always the same number of elements in the sub-arrays, denoted with m, and the outer array has a length of n, then O(nm) is more correct, sure. O(n^2) only works if n=m.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen ok, `O(n)` makes sense if you assume bounded size for the inner arrays and `O(n*m)` is also good if you don't want to assume anything about the inner array size. I inferred from OP's statement that this algorithm  `probably is O(n^2)`, that `m = Theta(n)`, the only case where the algorithm is `Theta(n^2)` in the outer array size. (May have been too quick an assumption.) @OP: If you actually want to know about the algorithms complexity (I don't think it is really relevant), you should specify what your limit parameter is and how the array sizes depend on it.

Comment: But tangential to the discussion about whether this is O(N) or O(NM), the problem here is that the expensive operation is the insert, and this still have to be performed on *every* object. How you count these objects may differ (N vs. NM), but you still need to either 1) reduce the cost of the expensive operation, ie. make the insert operation cheaper, or 2) reduce the number of elements. Neither of these optimizations has sort of a fixed number of steps you can perform. Basically, this question is impossible to answer with the little information we have.

Comment: You will need to find a different way to insert the elements. For instance, many database engines have bulk insert operations that you can give a collection of rows to, which performs sometimes orders of magnitude faster than inserting one element at a time. Since we know nothing about the technology you use here while inserting one element at a time it is quite impossible for us to give you advise on how, or even if, you can do that.

Comment: The general methods you can apply in order to optimize something is to 1) do it faster (ie. make the thing you're doing quicker), 2) do it fewer times (not really an option here), 3) find a different way of doing it (like bulk insert)

Answer (score 1):

This is slow because you have 100,000 database operations, not because you're scanning the array. You should batch your DB operations so that you insert many values at once.